# How can this code print Hello World without any print statement

Tags: python

I found this code in Python, which prints "Hello World" without the use of  the string "Hello World". It's a one line code, a single expression (i.e. no print statement).

```
(lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______, ________: getattr(__import__(True.__class__.__name__[_] + [].__class__.__name__[__]), ().__class__.__eq__.__class__.__name__[:__] + ().__iter__().__class__.__name__[_____:________])(_, (lambda _, __, ___: _(_, __, ___))(lambda _, __, ___: chr(___ % __) + _(_, __, ___ // __) if ___ else (lambda: _).func_code.co_lnotab, _ << ________, (((_____ << ____) + _) << ((___ << _____) - ___)) + (((((___ << __) - _) << ___) + _) << ((_____ << ____) + (_ << _))) + (((_______ << __) - _) << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << ___) + (_ << _))) + (((_______ << ___) + _) << ((_ << ______) + _)) + (((_______ << ____) - _) << ((_______ << ___))) + (((_ << ____) - _) << ((((___ << __) + _) << __) - _)) - (_______ << ((((___ << __) - _) << __) + _)) + (_______ << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << __))) - ((((((_ << ___) + _)) << __) + _) << ((((___ << __) + _) << _))) + (((_______ << __) - _) << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << _))) + (((___ << ___) + _) << ((_____ << _))) + (_____ << ______) + (_ << ___))))(*(lambda _, __, ___: _(_, __, ___))((lambda _, __, ___: [__(___[(lambda: _).func_code.co_nlocals])] + _(_, __, ___[(lambda _: _).func_code.co_nlocals:]) if ___ else []), lambda _: _.func_code.co_argcount, (lambda _: _, lambda _, __: _, lambda _, __, ___: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______: _, lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______, ________: _)))
```

As it is a single line code, [Here's](http://codepad.org/UzSmoxF2) a well formatted code which is more readable.

It is made up of only functions, attribute access, lists, tuples, basic math, one True, and one star-args. It has minimal builtin usage (`__import__`, `getattr`, and `chr` once each).

It's really hard for me to understand it. Is there any possible explanation of what it does?

[Here](https://benkurtovic.com/2014/06/01/obfuscating-hello-world.html), by the way, is where the author of the code explains how it works.

Comment: See [here](https://benkurtovic.com/2014/06/01/obfuscating-hello-world.html) the explanation.

Comment: Why have you not cited the source of the code?

Comment: @Boris Thank you for the edit. But I don't think it's fair to add a link from the answer to the question. I should make the edit to cite the source of the code.

Comment: That's "run away screaming"-tier Python code.

Comment: Seriously, dude: [the question and answer on Stackoverflow](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22533/weirdest-obfuscated-hello-world); [the link to the author's webpage with further info](http://benkurtovic.com/2014/06/01/obfuscating-hello-world.html). It is called "citing your sources" and you [**should do it**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: That said, this is a very bad question with no value. You could have had a specific problem, and asked about a detail; as it stands, it is just _knowingly_ posting someone else's code without citing.

Comment: I've added the citation as you said. It really seems that the question was taken from the site.

Comment: @Boris Odd that it got 10 votes in under an hour. I guess there must be a lot of like-minded people on the site this morning.

Comment: @Alex It was posted on the r/programming subreddit. Promptly downvoted, but enough compulsive clickers got to click on it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to the question as written: The code avoids a `print` statement by `os.write()`ing to `stdout`'s file descriptor, which is `1`:

```
getattr(__import__("os"), "write")(1, "Hello world!\n")
```

The rest of the explanation is detailed at https://benkurtovic.com/2014/06/01/obfuscating-hello-world.html. Instead of a summary here, just read the original!

Comment: This is mindblowing...